# Issue in Struts migration from 2.1.8 to 2.3.32

Tags: struts2, migration

> Caught exception while registering interceptor class
>   org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor-interceptor

Facing this error while migrate Struts from 2.1.8 to 2.3.32

Comment: Please read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question.

Comment: The amount of effort you put in this question is disturbing

Comment: Can you provide a list of jars and maybe your struts xml (dummy version) ?

Answer (score 0):

[AnnotationValidationInterceptor](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/interceptor/validation/AnnotationValidationInterceptor.html) is already registered in `struts-default.xml`.

To use this interceptor your package should extend `struts-default`. See how to [package configuration](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/package-configuration.html).

```xml
<struts>
  <package name="employee" extends="struts-default"...
```